# Most efficient way to find if a value exists within a C# List

Tags: c#, list

In C# if I have a List of type bool. What is the fastest way to determine if the list contains a true value?  I don’t need to know how many or where the true value is.  I just need to know if one exists.  I will be searching many extremely large lists.

Comment: Kind of depends on how you populate that list. List<bool>.Any() should get you what you want, but it is still a worst case O(N).

Comment: (It's *effectively* a duplicate of that, anyway.)

Comment: If you'll be searching more than storing these values, and speed is really critical, you could store separately for each list whether it has a true value.

Comment: How large is extremely large? 4,000,000,000+ items?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use either list.Contains(true) or list.Any(true).
For a normal list both have complexity O(n). Since Any() is an extension method though, which needs to invoke delegates, the Contains() might still be a bit faster. But to be sure I would simply test both with a large collection.

Comment: Thanks treze.  Based on what your saying I try both and see what's faster.

Comment: @AaronBenzel Also try the loop approach from my answer and see if that's any faster for you. It seems it is on some systems.

Comment: Like you say, the relevant `Any` overload needs a delegate. You say `list.Any(true)`, but `true` is no delegate, so that won't compile. If you want to use LINQ (for some crazy reason) its method is called `Contains` as well. To call the LINQ `Contains`, either use `list.AsEnumerable().Contains(true)` (where the `AsEnumerable` ensures that the instance methods of `List<>` itself do not apply) or use `list.Contains<bool>(true)` (where the presence of a generic argument rules out the non-generic instance method of `List<>`). But as lazyberezovsky said elsewhere: Why use LINQ if you have `List<>`?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen You are of course right about the signature. And I also see no reason in using LINQ, just wanted to state the two possibilities I see.

Answer (score 24):

Just use `bool trueInList = list.Contains(true);`. This loops the list until there's a `true`.

Why do you need something faster with such a simple use-case?

Comment: +1 why use Linq if you have List :)

Comment: (Reinstated comment) I would use this simple approach, but I want to point out that a hand-rolled loop is more than 3 times faster - see my answer below.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Your answer seems to be deleted now.

Answer (score 6):

You could use Any().

```
list.Any(b => b);
```

Comment: Certainly not the fastest option because of the delegate call.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var result = myBoolList.Any(i => i==true);
```

Comment: If it's nullable I would consider `==true`, why add it now?

Comment: Wait, LINQ has a special method for the pattern `.Any(x => x==WANTED)`, and it is called `.Contains(WANTED)`. (This assumes that the compile-time overload of `==` has the same behavior as the ___virtual___ `object.Equals(object)` method, but that is the case here.)

Answer (score 1):

You use the `Any(...)`

```
list.Any(c => c == true);
```

or just

```
list.Any(c => c);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use BinarySearch method of the list.

```
if(list.BinarySearch(true) > 0){...}
```

Comment: No you can't. Why would the list be ordered?

Comment: Even if the list was sorted (which would be strange for a `List<bool>`), it's incorrect to say `>0`. It should be `>=0`. The list could be very short and have only `true` entries, then the `BinarySearch` might return `0` meaning: I found a match at index `0`, so `list[0]` matches.

Answer (score 1):

This answer provides a different angle on this: Why store the bools in a list? Store them as two ints: `int falseCount; int trueCount;`.

Contains-testing is as simple as: `trueCount > 0`

Assuming that you need the list, use `List.Contains` as it directly searches the underlying array.

It would be even faster to extract the underlying array using reflection and search it in a hard-coded comparison loop. You can use the literal `true` there to compare each element. You can even unroll the loop or do unsafe code tricks.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool val = false;
Foreach(bool val in listofvalue)
{
   val |= val;
}

if(val)
print "List contain true value"

else

print "List contain false value"
```

Comment: No need to iterate through all the values just to figure out if one of them is true

Comment: It's called `|=` not `=||`. But @treze is right, no need for OR'ing them all together.

Comment: sorry friends............:(