# JIT optimizations for dictionaries with value type keys

Tags: c#, performance, dictionary, jit

Are there any optimizations done by the Jitter to avoid boxing and to reject branches of code that cannot be taken depending on what a generic argument is? E.g. in the default equality comparer used by a `Dictionary<int, TValue>` the comparer implementation will be the `GenericEqualityComparer<int>`, as I understand it because `int` implements `IEquatable<T>`. The Equals method of this comparer looks like this:

```
public override bool Equals(T x, T y)
{
  if ((object) x != null)
  {
    if ((object) y != null)
      return x.Equals(y);
    else
      return false;
  }
  else
    return (object) y == null;
}
```

What will a jitted version of this method look like? In the case where T is a value type, can this be optimised to just effectively comparing x to y, and ignoring the comparisons with null?

Using a custom comparer with the trivial implementation of Equals and GetHashCode(), I get a slightly *worse* performance than the dictionary with a default comparer! This could be random benchmark noise, but the difference appeared to be quite consistent.

```
   public bool Equals(int a, int b) { return a == b; }
   public int GetHashCode(int obj) { return obj; }
```

Even stranger was that when I created a reverse engineered Dictionary class by recompiling it *without* the comparer field entirely, effectively hard-coding it for integer keys by inlining GetHashCode-calls with the key itself and Equals-calls with a simple equality, the performance was even worse. My only interpretation of this is that:

- Value types implementing `IEquatable<T>` will get a default equality comparer created inside the dictionary, whose performance for types such as `int` is at least equivalent to the trivial comparer.
- The GetHashCode/Equals calls done by the Dictionary are either irrelevant from a performance perspective, or they are inlined so that the call to `comparer.GetHashCode(TKey key)` will effectively be replaced by just the integer value at JIT time.

Are these assumptions correct?

Comment: I don't think the JIT will optimize it. I had a similar question about `List.Contains()` being slow, and some of the answers discussed such optimisations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16062154/loop-implementation-of-list-contains-appears-faster-than-the-built-in-one-is

Comment: @MatthewWatson in the accepted answer to that question the author says that "the baseline JIT compiler does not optimize away the boxing". What I'm seeing is the opposite here: there is no trace of boxing, so maybe when optimized the boxing *is* removed?